# Thymeleaf - Add attribute without value

Tags: thymeleaf

In Thymeleaf I would like to generate following HTML

```
<span data-my-attr>
</span>
```

I would like to display `data-my-attr` conditionally, but there seems to be no way how to display or NOT to display an empty attribute conditionally.

In case of `required` attribute there is `th:required` but for custom attributes there is nothing.

I tried to use `th:attr="'data-my-attr'=${value}"` and value is `true` or `false`, but it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume `condition` is `true` when your attribute should be shown and `false` when it shouldn't. You can have following:

```
<span data-my-attr th:attr="${condition} ? 'meaningless' : 'data-my-attr'=''"></span>
```

Explanation:

According to [this thread](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Remove-an-html-attribute-td4024880.html) when you specify the empty value for an attribute within `th:attr` then Thymeleaf will delete this attribute. So in above snippet:

1. `data-my-attr` is added by default.
2. The empty value is assigned to an attribute using `th:attr`.
3. The name of the attribute overriden with empty value is selected accordingly to `${condition}`.
4. When `${condition}` is `true` then `data-my-attr` should stay so any meaningless name (not present within the tag) should be picked.
5. Otherwise `data-my-attr` should be deleted so this name is picked.

Feels hacky but such a way of attribute removal seems working since 2012. Therefore I'd consider it stable.

Comment: thanks, your solution works. It's a hacky and 'hard-to-read' one, but I think we don't have anything better in Thymeleaf.

Comment: @michal.jakubeczy Another way I thought of is `<th:block th:if="{$condition}"><span data-my-attr></span></th:block><th:block th:unless="${condition}"><span></span></th:block>`. Less hacky but more verbose.

Comment: yes, sure that is an option too. But disadvantage is a lot of code duplicity. I was wondering why `[(${expression ? 'data-my-attribute' : ''})]` inside element is not working. That would be a great way to do it.

Comment: I think code duplicity can be avoided by using `th:fragment`. But sure, an expression you've mentioned would be an advantage. It might be a good idea to raise an issue in Thymeleaf's github repository with a request to support adding of custom "boolean attributes" conditionally.

Comment: yeah, might be a good one. Is is still maintained btw?

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure.